# FlatList doesn't show anything when retrieving data with redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to use FlatList but it doesn't show anything even though the data provided to the list is correct (I console logged it above the render() and it showed the array just fine)

I tried to map the Libraries and then pass it to the component but that just made the array repeat itself on the screen 9 times (which is the array length)

```
` 

renderItem(Library){
        return <ListItem myLibrary={Library} />
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <FlatList 
            data={this.props.Libraries}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={Library => Library.title}
            />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {Libraries: state.Libraries}
}
`
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RenderLibraries); `

and in the other component:

```
         `  <Text>
                {this.props.myLibrary.title}
            </Text> `
```

Comment: try this this.props.myLibrary.item.title

Comment: @CuongTranDuc It worked, Than you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Each item of data passed to renderItem will be wrapped inside item object. check the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)

```
renderItem({ item }){
    return <ListItem myLibrary={item} />
}
```